# Changing all labels alpha with animation is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to change the alpha of all the labels inside some area, but with animation.
So, i can change their alpha , but the animation won't happen for some reason (? )

```
  for(UIView * subViews in [subView subviews])
                    {
                            if([subViews isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                            {

                                UILabel *l=(UILabel*) subViews;

                                [UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                                 animations:^{ l.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
}
                                                 completion:nil];
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: Why just text colour instead of the alpha of the view?

Comment: Have tried also : l.alpha=1.0 and its not working

Comment: The `textColor` is not animatable...

Comment: @matt you are so wrong. how do you know they already have alpha? their alpha is 0 before !!

Comment: @Bannings so what does? how do you change alpha with animation ?

Comment: @Curnelious Set alpha of the label to 0 (not color) at first, then change it to 1 into animation block

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that with the help of @ Bannings

I had to change the alpha of the label it self, not its text alpha :
In this case : `l.alpha=1.0`